# Visual Studio 2015 RC Team Explorer Page Not Found Error on Builds Tab

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, team-explorer

I am using VS 2015 RC with a TFS 2012 server.  Everything in the team explorer works just fine, except for the Builds tab.  It just displays a "Page Not Found" error.  Is this a backwards compatibility issue?  Is there a way to make this work?  Or do I need to upgrade my TFS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams to be a compability issue.
Read more here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7c8c7290-e895-4f67-a980-46884845900e/error-tf200016-in-vs2015-build-tab?forum=visualstudiogeneral